# Updating graphs with callback in dash plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, analytics, plotly-dash

I've already searched everywhere but can't find a way to build a callback to update my graphs in real time properly, can someone give me advices?
The aim is to receive the data through sensors with arduino, but for testing i'm creating random values to plot.
Here is the rep: https://github.com/Gugarauj07/RacingTelemetry_Visualization

This is how i initialy plot the graphs:

```
graph_temperature = go.Figure(layout={"template": "plotly_dark"})
graph_temperature.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["tempo"], y=df["temp_obj"], name="temp_obj", mode="lines", line=dict(color="#F6511D")))
graph_temperature.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df["tempo"], y=df["temp_amb"], name="temp_amb", mode="lines", line=dict(color="#FFB400")))
graph_temperature.update_layout(yaxis_title="Temperatura CVT", margin=dict(l=5, r=5, t=5, b=5), autosize=True,
                                height=150)
```

How should i program my callback to update this types of graphs, and not losing the layout?

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output('graph_temperature', 'figure'),
        # Output('graph_velocidade', 'figure'),
        # Output('graph_RPM', 'figure'),
        # Output('graph_ACC', 'figure'),
        # Output('graph_laps', 'figure'),
    ],
    Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
)
def update_graphs(num):
    if num == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        graph_temperature = {

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not losing the layout?

Comment: the margins and height that i setted before

Comment: Did you dcc.Graph() in Dash?

Comment: yeah, i did it.

Comment: What's wrong with that?